# Excel Filter Function - choose certain columns as output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to apply a Filter function on multiple columns ranging from `A:G` and only have columns `B`,`D` in the output. How can I do it?

For Example `=FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)` results in a spilled array of rows that match the condition, but the output will still have 7 columns(`A:G`). Can I choose to only output Column `B` & `D`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use `CHOOSE` like this:

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},B1:B7,D1:D7),$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)
```

This also allows you to reorder columns in the output by changing their order in the `CHOOSE` function.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but getting an error. Can you help me understand how to select Column `D` & `G` from `C1:K7`? from this output: `=FILTER(C1:K7,M1:M7=M1)`

Comment: Just change `B1:B7,D1:D7` to `D1:D7,G1:G7`

Comment: I see, so do we need to specify each output range individually? I'm a little confused on how it works on a continuous range. For example if I need `B1:E7` & `G1:H7`

Comment: Yes, you need to do each column, in whatever order you want them output.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. So it allows you to choose the order of output as well. I think you should mention this in the answer.

Answer (score 28):

## TL;DR

1. **Option1**:

   ```
   =FILTER(FILTER(A1:G7,K1:K7=K1),{0,1,0,1,0,0,0})
   ```
2. **Option2**: - [Reference](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/filter-non-adjacent-columns/#:%7E:text=use%20the%20INDEX%20function)

   ```
   =FILTER(INDEX(tblData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblData)),{4,3,5}),tblData[Customer Name]=I3)
   ```
3. **Option3**: - [Answered by Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69577256/6908282)

   ```
   =FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},B1:B7,D1:D7),$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)
   ```
4. **Option4**: - Commented by P.b

   ```
   =FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(B:B))+(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(D:D)))
   ```

---

## Explanation

### Option 1

You can nest the original `FILTER` function inside `another FILTER` function and specify an array of `1`'s and `0`'s mentioning which column you need and which you don't.

For Example, in the above question if I want only Column B & D, I can do this:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A1:G7,K1:K7=K1),{0,1,0,1,0,0,0})
```

Since B & D are the 2nd & 4th columns, you need to specify a `1` at that position in the array

---

Similarly if you want to filter columns from `C:K` and only output columns `C`, `D` & `G`, then your formula would be:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(C1:K7,M1:M7=M1),{1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0})
```

#### Pros & Cons - Option1

- This formula is the simplest of all and easy to understand
- You can **NOT** change the order of output. You can only hide/unhide in the original sequence
- You can apply this on a Range of multiple columns without much change

### Option2

Another way to do this which is complex looking is this:
Note that this method allows you to change the order of output columns. You can refer to [following site](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/filter-non-adjacent-columns/#:%7E:text=use%20the%20INDEX%20function) for detailed explanation on how this works.

```
=FILTER(INDEX(tblData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblData)),{4,3,5}),tblData[Customer Name]=I3)
```

#### Pros & Cons - Option2

- This formula looks complex, but is straight-forward once you understand the logic
- You can change the order of output columns as required
- You can apply this on a Range of multiple columns without much change

### Options 3

This is actually the [answer provided by Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69577256/6908282)

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},B1:B7,D1:D7),$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)
```

#### Pros & Cons - Option3

- This formula is complex, especially for returning a range of continuous columns
- You need to explicitly mention each output column individually
- You can change the order of output columns as required
- Applying this on to output multiple continuous ranges gets tricky (For Example you cannot replace `B1:B7` with `B1:C7` in above formula)

### Options 4

Based on comment from P.b below

```
=FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(B:B))+(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(D:D)))
```

#### Pros & Cons - Option4

- This formula is the simple and somewhat similar to option 1.
- You can **NOT** change the order of output. You can only hide/unhide in the original sequence
- You can apply this on a Range of multiple columns without much change

---

There's a similar question that's asked in [reference to Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776051/how-to-take-only-certain-columns-from-a-filter-result). But Google Sheet also has the `Query` function which explicitly supports choosing specific columns

Comment: Another altnative `=FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(B:B))+(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(D:D)))`

Comment: Interesting. Let me make sure I understood it right -- Does this mean, "**filter `A:G` based on `K1:K7=$K$1` and choose columns `B` and `D`**"?

Comment: You create your filter over A:G by condition of K:K, like you had and you filter the result for the columns in your filtered range being equal to the given columns.

Comment: oh of course. makes sense. Is there a way to change the order of columns?

Comment: `=SORT(FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(B:B))+(COLUMN(A:G)=COLUMN(D:D))),,-1,1)` you can reverse the column order by wrapping in SORT (by column)

Answer (score 15):

Try the new CHOOSECOLS function ([beta channel](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows#2-Choose-an-Insider-level) at time of writing):

```lisp
=CHOOSECOLS(filtered_array, {2,4})
```

<sub>**Update 2024:** Now widely available, see [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choosecols-function-bf117976-2722-4466-9b9a-1c01ed9aebff#:%7E:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft,for%20the%20web)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**By far the easiest way of doing this.**

Apply range, your selection of columns in the preferred order and with the option to work your way in from the right side with `-`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FilteredRange,2,4)

=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),2,4)

=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),4,2) 'Custom order

=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($A$1:$G$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1),-6,-4)  'From the right side
```

Answer (score 1):

I use option #2 exclusively these days, but using a range of cells instead of the array.

```
=FILTER(INDEX(tblZero,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblZero)),A2:M2),tblZero[TakenBy]=A1)
```

Using the [#Headers] of my Table gives me column headings as well.

```
=FILTER(INDEX(tblZero[#Headers],SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblZero[#Headers])),A2:M2),'Zero Dollar Review Data'!A1<>"")
```

I use the row directly above the column headings to hold the column numbers.  This way, I simply have to enter a column number and I get both the column heading and the data.  I can also use some simple formulas in my column number cells to create outputs that are custom to the criteria used.  So if I enter "TBT" as my TakenBy value I can display a set of columns unique for that particular Rep., then if I enter "DXD", I can display a different set of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, create 2 separate columns for B `=FILTER($B$1:$B$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)`  and for D `=FILTER($D$1:$D$7,$K$1:$K$7=$K$1)`