# Excel FILTER return top 10 while skipping columns

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have some data in a table that I would like to filter and sort the top 10 from each column but not show all columns.

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

My current formula is as follows:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A3:I437,C3:C437>=LARGE(C3:C437,10)),3,-1)
```

This outputs the following:

[image: Output]

Ideally what I would like is to output just columns R and T from this formula but am not sure how to go about this? I will also be running the same formula to output column R with each of the other columns separately (e.g. R&S, R&U, R&V etc).

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, your current output is okay and you want to return column R and T from current output, right?

Comment: Have you tried searching on StackOverflow? its already there [Excel Filter Function - choose certain columns as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577167/excel-filter-function-choose-certain-columns-as-output)

Comment: Thanks guys, Greedo got me where I needed to be. I did see the other solution but couldn't see a clean and easy way to integrate it with the top 10 filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new CHOOSECOLS function if you have it:

```lisp
=CHOOSECOLS(filtered_array,{1,3})
```

If not then you can use `INDEX(filtered_array, 0, 1)` to choose the entire first column, `INDEX(filtered_array, 0, 3)` to choose the 3rd

Alternatively to get a formula in a single cell, you can also use a second FILTER, filtering the COLS() of the array to match {1,3}, although this is a bit more involved.

---

N.B. Here `filtered_array` is your current formula

Comment: You're a genius thank you! Also....that was a right PITA to get the Beta build, I had to figure out how to change my business org to have targeted releases and then install the beta channel on my machine, but I got there!! Both answers work beautifully though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also `CHOOSE` inside the `FILTER`

edit: like this

[Excel Filter Function - choose certain columns as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577167/excel-filter-function-choose-certain-columns-as-output)