# Why CHOOSE function doesn't return an dynamic array correctly?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I'm trying to use the CHOOSE function to return just a few non adjacents columns from a table, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69577168), but the result doesn't look correct.

Simulating the same problem in the table below, I realized that the result is the same.

[image]

What could be happening? This formula is not compatible with my version? The FILTER and UNIQUE formulas return a dynamic array correctly.

P.S.: "ESCOLHER" is equivalent function for CHOOSE in my language.

Comment: Change semicolon to comma. `=CHOOSE({1,2},B2:B7,E2:E7)`

Comment: semicolon is the default separator in my region, cmoma doesn't works.

Comment: Then you may need to use \, also what is your language, if you are using `Portuguese` then it should be `=SELECIONAR({1.2};B2:B7;E2:E7)`

Comment: No - you have to use a dot (.) to have a one row - two columns array: `=CHOOSE({1.2},B2:B7,E2:E7)`, comma returns a "column" with two rows ...

Comment: Using dot returns an error, but \ seems to work. This is a constant array, right? in documentation in my language, there's an example with comma, even this doesn't works. This is bizarre.

Comment: Then you might need to make changes on regional settings, i am not sure about, i made a guess because usually `Portuguese` and `Spanish` uses that slash

Comment: You may want to use `HSTACK(B2:B7,E2:E7)` so the separator is no issue. Though you tagged Excel 2021, which I believe doesn't support it.

Comment: @P.b Sir, no it still needs "\"

Comment: But then the default formula separator is used. For arrays, the vertical or horizontal separators are subject to variations in different languages.

Comment: Yes but default is semicolon. Then it should nt be `HSTACK(B2:B7;E2:E7)`

Comment: To identify the correct column separator for your system, just go to a new sheet, input 1 in cell `A1` and 2 in cell `B1`, then in cell `C1` type `=A1:B1` and press `F9` on your keyboard… voila! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Separators

- There are a few separators in Excel. Three (four) are of interest.
- One is called the **list** separator, and the other two are called the **row** and the **column** separators.
- This is a US website, so we kind of agree to use their separators: The US list and column separators are a comma (`,`), while the row separator is a semicolon (`;`).
- I still haven't heard that there is a different row separator in any language. So you can always define a single column with e.g. `{1;2}`. If you need a row, you can use `TOROW({1;2})`. If you don't have M365, you can use `TRANSPOSE({1;2})`. These should work in any language.
- In the formula `=HSTACK(B2:B7,E2:E7)`, the comma is the list separator and it is assumed that OP knows to replace the comma with his list separator, the semicolon.
- In the expression (array) `{1,2}` the comma is the column separator. Since OP's Excel uses the comma as a **decimal** separator, an alternative column separator is needed namely the backslash (`\`) as he has already discovered.
- Other languages might use different column separators e.g. a dot (`.`) as suggested by Mayukh Bhattacharya.
- Nevertheless, the more important question is: How do you discover your row and column separators?

**The Row Separator (Most Probably a Semicolon)**

- In the range `A1:A3` write the numbers `1,2,3`. Now in cell `B1` write the formula `=A1:A3` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now select `B1` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the formula and press <kbd>F9</kbd> to evaluate the formula. The result should be `={1;2;3}` (could be a different separator).  Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the formula.

**The Column Separator (Default (US) Is a Comma)**

- In the range `A1:C1` write the numbers `1,2,3`. Now in cell `D1` write the formula `=A1:C1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now select `D1` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the formula and press <kbd>F9</kbd> to evaluate the formula. The result will be `={1,2,3}` with a possibly different separator (e.g. `.`, `\`). Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Change semicolon to comma just in index expression `{1,2}`:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2};B2:B7;E2:E7)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't works. Semicolon is default separator for my region(portuguese-brazil)

Comment: Try a dot - see my comment

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya With \ seems to work correctly.